# CSS: min-height 100% (with fixed elements also on screen)?

Tags: html, expand, css

I have been trying to use the min-height:100% to get my content area to stretch to fill the remaining % of the screen, but I'm just plain stumped. Any help is appreciated.

I have 3 fixed height divs at the top of the screen and 1 fixed height footer. I then have another div where the non-fixed height portion lies, which is the "container" div. Within here I have both content and sidebar divs that I want to stretch out to 100% of screen at minimum, and expand to fit the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3Ckk/110/

Any and all help is appreciated. It's got me stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `#conatinerWide` set with a gray background and I'm assuming you want it to stretch to fill the rest of the are.

The thing is `html` and `body` will only expand large enough to fit the content you have. So setting those to 100% will tell it to fill the document window; allow your `#containerWide` to now be 100% available space.

Adding `html, body { height: 100%; }` should achieve what you are wanting

http://jsfiddle.net/rtgibbons/P3Ckk/111/

Update for comments;

You for every element you want a `min-height:100%` to be the size of the window you need to set the `height:100%` to the parent element. So `#containerWide` needs `height:100%` and `#container` needs `min-height:100%; height:100%`;. Now the fun part. If you do this same pattern for `#exsi` and `#cont` the will be the height of `#container` and not adjust for the space needed by `#foot`.

Here is where I'd continue at

http://jsfiddle.net/rtgibbons/P3Ckk/113/

Basically, I've set `min-height:100%; height:100%` on all the parents elements. I've moved `#foot` out of `#container` so it will be maxed out with the columns. Then I applied some negative margin-bottom of the Total Height of `#foot` so it will be sucked up inside `#containerWide`

Two caveats.

1. Padding with 100% was causing `#exsi` and `#cont` to expand past `#containerWide` so removing them and applying them to the inner elements as needed or yet another wrapper.
2. The footer will appear below the fold. This is b/c you are positioning `#containerWide`; I'll leave this as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: That's sorta what I wanted, but not exactly. Sorry wasn't clear. I just set those colors up to make it easier to see all the different divs. I actually want the #container to fill out WITH the #content and #exsi divs (yellow and orange) as well. So, the light grey should fill like it did in your example, but the yellow and orange would fill out the remaining space too, leaving the #foot (green) at the bottom. Also, I want this to just be a minimum so that when either the #content or #exsi divs have content beyond 100%... they expand (hopefully always expanding each other).

Comment: That becomes a bit more tricky. Updating my answer with the response

Comment: Thank you. That is perfect. Now, just so I understand... why is height:100% not going into the nav, top and title divs? Is it because those get in the way of the parent "containerWide" div? And don't enable to fill the entire 100%? And if so, then I guess that's a property of height 100%... it won't overlap divs, it'll simply be 100% of the leftover space? I just want to understand the logic behind it so I know what's going on for the future. Anyway, thank you again!!

Comment: I had a hard time follow all the questions in the comment. The best thing you can do is experiment to see how everything reacts. The reason we defined `height:100%` on the other elements are so that the `min-height:100%` will have something to go off of, they use the height of the parent element.